# OR clause inside JSON query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

In Postgres JSONB, is it possible to do something like this:

```
where (
  description ->'Auditor'->'1'->'Internal|External' is not null
)
```

Instead of this:

```
where (
  description ->'Auditor'->'1'->'Internal' is not null
  or
  description ->'Auditor'->'1'->'External' is not null
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether a jsonb value has any of a set of keys with `?|`:

```
where description->'Auditor'->'1' ?| array ['Internal','External']
```

[Relevant documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: Awesome. Interestingly `?|` is slower than using 2 separate queries. 3800ms vs 600ms previously.